# (Codeigniter) populating view's select with foreach and setting default value based on session data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently setting up an update company details page for my app (company timezone), I have already built and outputted a list of timezone/locale's grabbing PHP's inbuilt values for this and its all outputting fine.

My issue is I cannot for the life of me, work out how to set the 'selected' value when using a foreach to display the array into the select...

Model

```
//Timezone listing generated from PHP locales
function tz_list()
{
$zones_array = array();
$timestamp = time();
foreach(timezone_identifiers_list() as $key => $zone) {
    date_default_timezone_set($zone);
    $zones_array[$key]['zone'] = $zone;
    $zones_array[$key]['diff_from_GMT'] = 'UTC/GMT ' . date('P', $timestamp);
}
return $zones_array;
}
```

Controller

```
//set locale display
$data['userOrglocale'] = $this->session->userdata('locale');

//load locale list from model
$data['tz_list'] = $this->account_model->tz_list();
```

View

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Time Zone:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="ui-select">
            <select id="user_time_zone" class="form-control">

            <?php
                foreach($tz_list as $key => $value)
                {
                    if ($userOrglocale == $tz_list['zone'])
                    {
                       $selected = 'selected';
                    }
                echo '<option value=' . $key['zone'] . $selected . '>' . $value['zone'] . ' (' . $value['diff_from_GMT'] . ')</option>';
                }
             ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ability to do this without Javascript/AJAX would be nice (as I dont know it well/much/at all) but I understand there is only so much I can do with HTML/PHP too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but worked and kept the data as I needed it presented:
 Only change was within the **view**

```
<?php
foreach($tz_list as $key => $value)
{
    if ($userOrglocale == $value['zone'])
    {
    $selected = 'selected';
    }
    else
    {
    $selected = '';
    }
    echo '<option value="' . $value['zone'] . '"' . $selected . '>' . $value['zone'] . ' (' . $value['diff_from_GMT'] . ')</option>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**quotation issuse**.
you should change this

```
echo '<option value=' . $key['zone'] . $selected . '>' . $value['zone'] . ' (' . $value['diff_from_GMT'] . ')</option>';
```

**to**

```
echo '<option value="' . $key['zone'] .'" selected="'. $selected . '"'>' . $value['zone'] . ' (' . $value['diff_from_GMT'] . ')</option>';
```

**UPDATE 1**

Model

```
//Timezone listing generated from PHP locales
function tz_list()
{
$zones_array = array();
$timestamp = time();
foreach(timezone_identifiers_list() as $key => $zone) {
    date_default_timezone_set($zone);
    $zones_array[$zone] = 'UTC/GMT ' . date('P', $timestamp);
}
return $zones_array;
}
```

Controller

```
//set locale display
$data['userOrglocale'] = $this->session->userdata('locale');

//load locale list from model
$data['tz_list'] = $this->account_model->tz_list();
```

View

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Time Zone:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="ui-select">
            <?php
                echo form_dropdown(array('id' => 'user_time_zone'), $tz_list, $userOrglocale);
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this has changed nothing, it actually added a quotation issue? selected='selected' also isnt required, just 'selected' works fine

Comment: @BrianRamsey i know that selected is enough. check my update please.